# Find $\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to compute the following integral:
$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}~dx$$
I tried everything I know, including defining $u=x^2$ and $u=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but it failed.

Comment: Take x=$\sin \theta$

Comment: $$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \frac{(x^2-1)+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Can you treat both terms in isolation?

Comment: You forgot $\mathrm dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x = \sin(u)$, then we have $dx = \cos(u) du$

Substituting in above, we get:

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx = \int \frac{\sin^2(u)}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(u)}} \cdot \cos(u) du = \int\frac{\sin^2(u)}{\cos(u)} \cdot \cos(u) du = \int \sin^2(u) du$$

which solves to:

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot (u - \sin(u) \cos(u))$$

Now you can make the reverse substitution to get the desired result, which is:

$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\sin^{-1}(x) - \sin(\sin^{-1}(x)) \cos(\sin^{-1}(x))\right) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\sin^{-1}(x) - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\right)$$

which is the required answer. That is:

$$\color{red}{\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} dx = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\sin^{-1}(x) - \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\right)}$$

`NOTE:` The last step is due to the fact that:

$$\sin(\sin^{-1}(x)) = x\,, \textrm{and}\, \cos(\sin^{-1}(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$$

Comment: Joshi, how did you do $\int sin^2(u)du$?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Try the trigonometric substitution $x=\sin\theta.$ Keep the Pythagorean identity in mind.

Answer (score 0):

hint
$$\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{-(1-x^2)+1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\sin \theta$,
$$\mathrm dx=\cos \theta\mathrm d\theta$$
the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{\sin^2 \theta .\cos \theta }{\cos \theta}\mathrm d\theta.$$